# ANOVA on unevenly spaced time data

Tags: time-series, anova, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have a dataset with three treatments (P+, P- and T) and want to test the effect of the treatment on the mortality (continuous variable). Data are unevenly spaced in time. I decided to handel this by finding a function that caracterizes the data and then made an anova on the parameters of the model. Is this statistically correct? Is there a better way to do the analysis?

Here bellow is an example dataset and my R script.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
#Add library
library(ggplot2)
library(nlme)

# open an example file
m13 <- read.table(text="date ruche mortes trmt      
03.10.2013     1      8   P+        
04.10.2013     1      7   P+        
07.10.2013     1     34   P+       
03.10.2013     7     16   P+       
04.10.2013     7     68   P+       
07.10.2013     7    170   P+
03.10.2013     2      7   P-        
04.10.2013     2      7   P-       
07.10.2013     2     21   P-      
03.10.2013     5      8   P-       
04.10.2013     5     27   P-      
07.10.2013     5     24   P- 
03.10.2013     3     15    T       
04.10.2013     3      6    T    
07.10.2013     3     13    T    
03.10.2013     4      6    T    
04.10.2013     4     18    T    
07.10.2013     4     19    T ", h=T)


m13$asDate = as.Date(m13[,1], "%d.%m.%Y")
    m13$daysSinceDispl = as.numeric(m13$asDate - (m13$asDate[1]))

# Plot Data
r <- ggplot(m13, aes(x=daysSinceDispl, y=mortes, color=factor(trmt))) 
r +  geom_point() +geom_smooth() + ggtitle("Mortality in 2013") + theme(plot.title =element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"))

# Effect of trmt on mortality ?
# I see a knick in the datas at date x so split data in 2 datasets "early" and "late"
m13early<-m13[m13$daysSinceDispl<=1,]
    m13late<-m13[m13$daysSinceDispl>=1,]

m13earlyG<-groupedData(mortes~daysSinceDispl|ruche,data=m13early,outer=~trmt)
m13lateG<-groupedData(mortes~daysSinceDispl|ruche,data=m13late,outer=~trmt)

# make picewise linear function 
linM13e<-lmList(mortes~daysSinceDispl,data=m13earlyG)
linM13l<-lmList(mortes~daysSinceDispl,data=m13lateG)

plot(augPred(linM13e,level=0:1))
plot(augPred(linM13l,level=0:1))

## EARLY MORTALITY
#prepare file
m13earN<-m13early[m13early$daysSinceDispl==0,]
    m13earN.o<-m13earN[with(m13earN,order(m13earN$ruche)),]
m13earNdt<-data.frame(as.numeric(names(linM13e)),coef(linM13e))
names(m13earNdt)<-c("ruche","Int","slope")
m13earNdt.o<-m13earNdt[with(m13earNdt,order(m13earNdt$ruche)),]
m13earNdt.t<-data.frame(m13earNdt.o,m13earN.o[,"trmt"])
names(m13earNdt.t)<-c("ruche","Int","slope","trmt")

#Integer
avm13intT<-aov(cos(Int) ~ trmt, data=m13earNdt.t)
plot(avm13intT)
summary(avm13intT) #non signif

#Slope
avm13sloT<-aov(cos(Int) ~ trmt, data=m13earNdt.t)
plot(avm13sloT) #
summary(avm13sloT)# non signif. 

##LATE MORTALITY
#prepare file
m13latN<-m13late[m13late$daysSinceDispl==4,]
    m13latN.o<-m13latN[with(m13latN,order(m13latN$ruche)),]
m13latNdt<-data.frame(as.numeric(names(linM13l)),coef(linM13l))
names(m13latNdt)<-c("ruche","Int","slope")
m13latNdt.o<-m13latNdt[with(m13latNdt,order(m13latNdt$ruche)),]
m13latNdt.t<-data.frame(m13latNdt.o,m13latN.o[,"trmt"])
names(m13latNdt.t)<-c("ruche","Int","slope","trmt")

#Integer
avm13latIntT<-aov(cos(Int) ~ trmt, data=m13latNdt.t)
plot(avm13latIntT) 
summary(avm13latIntT) #non sign

#Slope
avm13latSloT<-aov(sin(slope) ~ trmt, data=m13latNdt.t)
plot(avm13latSloT) 
summary(avm13latSloT)# not signif p-val=0.0509
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on how your results are expected to be depedent on time and why the sampling intervals are not equal?

Comment: We study mortality of bees at hive entrance. This depends on wether conditions and stress, etc.. so varies over time. Sampling interval is not equal because the experimental design is not optimal. I firstly wanted to calcultate autocorrelation and include it in a simpler model but did not find a way to do this with my data.